# capture the error of c program in php

Tags: php, html

```html
<html>
<?php
$current="";
$answer="";

if(!empty($_POST))
{
 $current=$_POST['t1'];
 $file="hello.cpp";
 file_put_contents($file,$current);
 putenv("PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin");
 $error=shell_exec("g++  -Wall -o hello hello.cpp");
 $answer=shell_exec("hello.exe");
}
?>
<style>
.txtarea{
width:300px;
height:500px;}
</style>
<form method="POST">
<textarea name="t1" placeholder="Enter c++ code" class="txtarea"><?php echo $current; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="run">
<textarea name="t2" class="txtarea"><?php echo $answer; ?></textarea>
<br>
<textarea name="t3" class="t"><?php echo $error; ?></textarea>
</form>
</html>
```

I tried to run a c program written in the text-area and output it in another text-area. For testing I just write a simple hello world program and it worked properly. But the problem was that if I remove ";" from printf statement the error message was not stored in $error variable and the file "hello.exe" was also not created.
Is there any way to capture compilation error?
Here i am using dev c++ compiler.

Comment: You want `proc_open()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Comment: ohk  @alk I'll try

Comment: hii @alk proc_open() finally worked. but now im stuck at giving the input to scanf().. can you please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866566/pass-input-to-scanf-in-php-using-proc-open