# pass input to scanf in php using proc_open()

Tags: php, c, proc-open

Here is my php content

```html
<html>
<?php
$current="";
$answer="";
if(!empty($_POST))
{
 $descriptorspec = array(
 0 => array("pipe", "w"), 
 1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
 2 => array("file", "tmp/error-output.txt", "a")
 );
 $current=$_POST['t1'];
 $file="hello.cpp";
 file_put_contents($file,$current);
 putenv("PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin");
 $process = proc_open('g++  -Wall -o hello hello.cpp', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
 if (is_resource($process)) {
 fwrite($pipes[0],"12");
 fwrite($pipes[0],"/n");
 fwrite($pipes[0],"12");
 $answer=shell_exec("hello.exe");
 fclose($pipes[0]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
 }
}
?>
<style>
.txtarea{
width:300px;
height:500px;}
</style>
<form method="POST">
<textarea name="t1" placeholder="Enter c++ code" class="txtarea"><?php echo $current; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="run">
<textarea name="t2" class="txtarea"><?php echo $answer; ?></textarea>
<br>
<textarea name="t3" class="t"><?php echo $return_value; ?></textarea>
</form>
</html>
```

here goes c program that accepts input from proc_open()

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
 {
   int a,b,c;
   scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
   printf("Addition = %d",(a+b));
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output as "1" do not getting why 
Please help me out for storing the input to variables a and b and displaying the sum......
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to check if `scanf()` failed, and only if it didn't use `a` and `b` as else they stay uninitialised and using them would invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: how would I check if scanf() is failed or not, but when i executed the "hello.exe" file it shown the right output. @alk

Comment: Documentation to `scanf()` is here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

Comment: Better also use `proc_open()`.

Comment: Are you sure the `1` does not originate from `$return_value`?

Comment: yes because the value of $return_value is being printed in another textarea @alk